# awk in bash with ls and variable

Tags: bash, awk, ls

I wanted to print only the name of files of a specific directory:
In this way it works:

```
ls -g  --sort=size -r /bin | awk '{print $8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13}'
```

but if I read the path variable it doesn't work:

```
read PATH
ls -g  --sort=size -r $(PATH) | awk '{print $8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13}'
Command 'awk' is available in '/usr/bin/awk'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
ls -g  --sort=size -r ${PATH} | awk '{print $8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13}'
```

Notice the curly braces.

With `$(..)`, it'll execute the command/function named `PATH` and substitute the result, which is not what you want.

Note that `PATH` is the poor choice for a variable name as it will overwrite the system variable with the same name and make the system commands unavailable (since the original `PATH` has gone now). I suggest you use some other name such as `my_path`:

```
read my_path
ls -g  --sort=size -r ${my_path} | awk '{print $8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13}'
```

Answer (score 5):

This is exactly why you should not use UPPER_CASE_VARS. $PATH is a [variable used by the shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Variables) to find executables on your system. As soon as you over-write it with user input, your script can no longer find anything that does not reside in whatever the input was. In this case, you entered `/bin`, so your script can find `/bin/ls` but `awk` is not there.

The `command_not_found_handle` (see /etc/bash.bashrc) stepped in to give you a suggestion.