# How to get the files from a folder everyday and store it in another folder using shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I need to get the files present in a FTP location every day. other condition is I need the files only on that particular day, not in addition with older day files. then store the files in another folder using shell script

**Updated FTP script from comment from OP**

```
echo $HOST
echo $DATASET_A
echo $DATASET_B
ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT 
USER $USER
PASS $PASSWD
bin
prompt
lcd $New_DATASETS
cd $DATASET_A
mget *
cd $DATASET_B
mget *
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

Comment: Do you have anything to start with so far? can you add the code you have if you have something?

Comment: echo $HOST
echo $DATASET_A
echo $DATASET_B

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
bin
prompt

lcd $New_DATASETS

cd $DATASET_A
mget *
cd $DATASET_B
mget *

quit
END_SCRIPT

Comment: Can't you write a cron job executing daily on ftp server for copying files from one directory to other?

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
# above heredoc
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)   # adjust date format as required

# in heredoc
mget ${today}*          # adjust filename pattern as required
```

Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPSVARS -- one day you'll [accidentally overwrite $PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555060/awk-in-bash-with-ls-and-variable) and then wonder why your script is broken.