# Sourcing date hour in Bash

Tags: bash, scripting

I need to write a Bash script that source another script (config script) for hours. If the hour mentioned in config script matches the Linux past hour it needs to print the hour.

```
$ cat ConfHours.sh
#!/bin/bash --

Hours=(0 1 2 22 23)

$ cat Foo.sh

#!/bin/bash --
source /home/Geo/ConfHours.sh
arrayHours=( ${HOURS} )
for v in "${arrayHours[@]}"
do
HOUR=$(( $(date +%H) -1))
if [ "${HOUR}" == "v" ] ; then
HOUR = ${HOUR}
echo $HOUR
fi
done
```

When I run `Foo.sh`, I do not get anything. Could you please correct me where I am wrong?

Comment: `HOURS` is already an array. When you use `${HOURS}` you are only getting the first value from that array so `arrayHours` contains just one value, the first value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some errors:

```
source /home/Geo/ConfHours.sh
arrayHours=( ${HOURS} )
```

ConfHours defines a variable named `Hours` -- different variable

```
for v in "${arrayHours[@]}"
do
HOUR=$(date -d "1 hour ago" +%H)
```

You don't need to define this every time through the loop: put it before the `for` statement

```
if [ "${HOUR}" == "v" ] ; then
```

- missing `$` for the `v` variable
- $HOUR will contain a leading 0 (due to `%H`)
- a better test: `if (( 10#$HOUR == 10#$v ))`

```
HOUR = ${HOUR}
```

No spaces around the `=` allowed for variable assignment. Why are you trying to redefine the variable to itself?

```
echo $HOUR
fi
done
```

---

A more concise way to test an array contains a value is to take advantage of array string concatenation and pattern matching:

```
source ConfHours.sh
hour=$(date +%k)           # leading space, not leading zero
if [[ " ${Hours[*]} " == *" ${hour# } "* ]]; then 
    echo "$hour"
fi
```

All spaces and quotes are required.

Don't use UPPER_CASE_VARS: [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555060/7552)

Comment: Doesn't that concat test have substring matching problems if the array contains spaces in the values?

Comment: I am trying to compare previous hour e.g. right now is hour 23 I want to compare hour 22 from config file with current Linux hour. Could you please show me how to fix my code? Your code works when I do: hour=$(( $(date +%k) -1)) ; When I run script at hour 00 it should compare hour 23 from config file.

Comment: This is my updated script: arrayHours=( ${HOURS} )

for v in "${arrayHours[@]}"
do
HOUR=$(( $(date +%H) -1))
if [ "${HOUR}" == "$v" ] ; then
HOUR=${HOUR}
echo $HOUR
fi
done

Comment: Looks like you're ignoring all of my advice. What do you think this accomplishes: `HOUR=${HOUR}` ?? To answer your question: `hour=$(date -d "1 hour ago" +"%H")`

Comment: @EtanReisner, you're quite right. This array holds integers.