# Getopts doesn't work when there is a bash parameter before

Tags: bash, parameters, arguments, getopt

I have a problem with using getopts and simple bash parameters. My script write out from the file lines that match the specified expression.

-f option allows you to change file

-n option to change the number of lines written out

The first parametr $1 determines the type of expression

**Example file (file.txt):**

```
aaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbba
cccccccccccc
ab
ac
dddddddddddd
dgdgdgdgdgdg
abdbdbdbdbdb
```

**Example order:**

```
./script.sh a -f file.txt -n 2
```

**Example output:**

```
aaaaaaaaaaaa
ab
```

**My script:**

```
while getopts ":n:f:" opt
        do
        case $opt in
        (n)  
                argn=$OPTARG
                ;;
        (f)
                argf=$OPTARG
                ;;
        esac
        done

FOO=${argf:=/etc/passwd}
NR=${argn:=3}


echo " --------- ^$1 -----------"
awk -F':' '/^'"$1"'/ { print $1 }' $FOO | head -n $NR
```

It works only for example when I type

```
 ./script.sh a
```

or

```
./script.sh b
```

(giving me lines starting with this letter). Or when I just typed

```
 ./script.sh -n 5
```

or

```
./script -f file.txt
```

**It doesn't work when I want to use both parametr ($1) and the options. What can I do?**

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg A leading colon in the optstring means "silent mode".

Comment: Kk, I fixed it, but it is not the essence of the problem, because the script still "cannot see" options when there is a parameter before ($1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's how `getopts` works. It stops at the first non-option argument.

If you want to do what you are asking about (and I wouldn't recommend it by the way) then you get to either manually strip your option first (and call `getopts` normally) or pass the rest of the arguments to `getopts` manually.

So either

```
opt1=$1
shift

while getopts ":n:f:" opt
....
done

echo " --------- ^opt1 -----------"
```

or

```
while getopts ":n:f:" opt "${@:2}"
....
done

echo " --------- ^$1 -----------"
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Etan. Here's what you *should* do:

```
# I like to declare my vars up front
# your use of FOO=${argf:=/etc/passwd} is of course OK

file=/etc/passwd
max_matches=3

while getopts ":n:f:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        n) max_matches=$OPTARG ;;
        f) file=$OPTARG ;;
        :) echo "missing argument for option -$OPTARG"; exit 1 ;;
       \?) echo "unknown option -$OPTARG"; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))    # remove the processed options 
pattern=$1             # NOW, get the search term.

grep -m "$max_matches" "^$pattern" "$file"
```

And then you'll execute it with:

```
./script.sh -f file.txt -n 2 a
./script.sh -f file.txt a
./script.sh -n 2 a
./script.sh a
```

Note, [don't use ALL_CAPS_VARS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27556282/7552)