# Assign output values in one variable using separators

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
  RECORDS=$(aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $HOSTED_ZONE_ID \
   | $JQ -r '.ResourceRecordSets[] | select (.Name == "ap.com.") | .Name')
```

The Output value from $RECORDS prints in the format shown below in separated lines.

```
>> echo "recordType: $RECORDS"
recordType: ap.com.
ap1.com.
ap2.com.
```

How to print output in the format as (in inverted commas separating by comma)

```
>> echo "recordType: $RECORDS"
recordType: "ap.com, ap1.com, ap2.com"
```

Answer (score 4):

I would read the jq output into an array, and use bash's own ability to join things:

```sh
# redirect from a process substitution into mapfile 
mapfile -t records < <(aws ...| jq ...)

printf 'recordType: "%s"\n' "$(IFS=,; echo "${records[*]}")"
```

That joins with just a comma, not comma+space:

```
recordType: "ap.com.,ap1.com.,ap2.com."
```

---

Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as
reserved by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then
[wonder why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555060/7552)
[your script is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).

Comment: I'd like to +10 just for the recommendation to stop using ALLCAPS.  I think all shell related answers should contain that advice until that practice is purged from the world

Comment: Is there an 'official' source of the recommendation of not using ALLCAPS ? We see many examples of using it, like ORACLE_HOME, JAVA_HOME, or DOCKER_HOST, which is much more recent than the first two.

Comment: I suppose I should say "don't use allcaps _local_ or _script_ variables". Conventionally, environment variables are allcaps. And I would not expect there to be an official source: it's not up to the GNU bash maintainers to tell programmers not to make mistakes.

Comment: That makes much more sense. But if we look at `configure` script of bash source, we can see loads of ALLCAPS local or script variables, like PACKAGE_NAME, PACKAGE_VERSION, ... How can we explain it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this line :

```
echo "recordType: $RECORDS"|sed -e "s/\.$/\", /"|sed -e "s/ap/\"ap/"|tr -d '\r\n'| rev | cut -c 3- | rev
```

Not probably the most short and efficient but it works ;) (and it could be easily customize)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
echo recordType:\"$RECORDS\"|sed 's/ /,/g'|sed 's/:/: /'
```

Where the first sed to replace the commas, the second one to add the one space after the colon.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change slightly your jq command :

```
records=$(aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $HOSTED_ZONE_ID \
   | $JQ -r '[.ResourceRecordSets[] | select (.Name == "ap.com.") | .Name]|join(", ")')
```