# How to divide lines of a file into other files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

Im not of a programer myself but developed a shellscript to read a positional file and based on a single letter specified at position 16 copy all the line to another file.

Exemple:

INPUT FILE
003402841000011**A**10CNPJ08963394000195
003402841000041**B**20CNPJ08963394000195  16012020XX5313720087903007
003402841000011**A**10CNPJ08963394000195
003402841000041**B**20CNPJ08963394000195  16012020XX5313720087903007

OUTPUT FILE A
003402841000011**A**10CNPJ08963394000195
003402841000011**A**10CNPJ08963394000195
OUTPUT FILE B
003402841000041**B**20CNPJ08963394000195  16012020XX5313720087903007
003402841000041**B**20CNPJ08963394000195  16012020XX5313720087903007

The code i current have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ARQ_IN="$1";
DIR_OUT="C:/Users/etc/etc/";

while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; 
do 

SUBSTRING=$(echo $line| cut -c16);

if [ $SUBSTRING == "A" ]
then
    echo "$line" >> "$DIR_OUT"arqA.txt;
else
    if [ $SUBSTRING == "B" ]
    then
        echo "$line" >> "$DIR_OUT"arqB.txt;
    else
        if [ $SUBSTRING == "K" ]
        then
            echo "$line" >> "$DIR_OUT"arqK.txt;
        else
            if [ $SUBSTRING == "1" ]
            then
                echo "$line" >> "$DIR_OUT"arq1.txt;
            else
            
            fi
        fi
    fi
fi


done < "$ARQ_IN"
```

Although this code works, it doesn't work in the speed that i need, the INPUT FILE has around 400k registers.

Can someone help me to write a new code or improve this one?

Comment: You are right that you are looking for a different approach, like `awk`. Just for the learning process 2 remarks: In `SUBSTRING=$(echo $line| cut -c16)` you should use quotes around `$line`. You can often avoid nested if-then-else blocks with `case ... esac`.

Comment: Probably not relevant in your input data, but if $SUBSTRING is a space, `[ $SUBSTRING == x ]` will throw an error. Always quote your variables, unless you know exactly when not to.

Comment: Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as
reserved by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then
[wonder why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555060/7552) 
[your script is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for `awk`, could you please try following, though I haven't tested it with huge dataset but it should be definitely faster than OP's current approach. To add abosulte path before output file name we could pass shell variable into `awk` variable and get it in `outputFile` variable here.

```
awk '
{
  close(outputFile)
  outputFile=("output_file_"substr($0,16,1))
  print >> (outputFile)
}
' Input_file
```

With complete folder path to save files use following, please change `/tmp/test/` with your actual path here.

```
DIR_OUT="/tmp/test/"
awk -v folder="${DIR_OUT}" '
{
  close(outputFile)
  outputFile=(folder"arq"substr($0,16,1)".txt")
  print >> (outputFile)
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: holy.. this worked perfectly. But i dont quite understand the logic, can you teach me? Also in the Input_File i would like to add something like ...  }' "$DIR_IN""$ARQ_IN" (file directory plus file name) because this script wont stay in the same folder as the input file

Comment: @IcaroAmerico, your welcome. Usually I add detailed explanations in solutions but it was late night so I slept after adding this :) let me add some in comments, don't want to edit it as of now, cheers. Will add comments in few mins or so.

Comment: @IcaroAmerico, Here is the explanation for above solution. `close(outputFile)`-->closing outputFile(output file) in backend here to avoid `too many opened files error`. `outputFile=("output_file_"substr($0,16,1))`--> Creating outputFile which has output file name along with substrig of current line's 17th character. `print >> (outputFile)` printing current line into output file. I hope this helps you, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, bash while-read loops can be pretty slow, plus there's no need to call out to `cut` to get a substring. Try this:

```sh
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do 
    # the offset is zero-based, so use 15 not 16
    letter=${line:15:1}
    case "$letter" in
        [ABK1]) echo "$line" >> "${DIR_OUT}arq${letter}.txt" ;;
    esac
done < "$ARQ_IN"
```

With cascading if-else if, use `elif`

```sh
if some condition; then
    some action
elif some other condition; then
    some other action
...
else
    some default action
fi
```