# Variable in variablenames

Tags: bash

i have a a couple of variables with a number in its names. e.g

```
SERVER_IP48_SUBNET
..
SERVER_IP60_SUBNET
```

And an additional variable

```
SERVER_IP
```

Im trying to expand/concatenate them in the following way:

```
ALLIPs=${SERVER_IP}
  for i in {48..64}; do
    ALLIPs=${ALLIPs},${SERVER_IP${i}_SUBNET}
  done
```

as you can imagine this script fails saying:
Wrong substitution

Does anybody of you know a good solution for this problem?
Thanks so far

Answer (score 3):

Use a nameref with bash version 4.3 +

```
ALLIPs=${SERVER_IP}

for i in {48..64}; do
    declare -n tmp="SERVER_IP${i}_SUBNET"
    ALLIPs+=",$tmp"
done
```

---

But you should really be using an array in the first place:

```sh
server_ip=0.0.0.0
subnet_ip=(
    [48]=1.1.1.1
    [49]=2.2.2.2
    # ...
    [64]=16.16.16.16
)

all_ips=( "$server_ip" )
for i in {48..64}; do
    all_ips+=( "${subnet_ip[i]}" )
done

(
  IFS=,
  echo "ALLIPs = ${all_ips[*]}"
)
```

- Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as
  reserved by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then
  [wonder why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555060/7552)
  [your script is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).

---

I just noticed, if you just want a to join the IP addresses with commas, and you're using an array, you don't need a loop at all:

```sh
all_ips=$(
  IFS=,
  set -- "$server_ip" "${subnet_ip[@]}"
  echo "$*"
)
```

Comment: `declare -n tmp; for tmp in SERVER_IP{48..64}_SUBNET; do ALLIPs+=",$tmp"; done` would be more idiomatic. And while declaring the array, `subnet_ip=([48]=1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2)` is the same as `subnet_ip=([48]=1.1.1.1 [49]=2.2.2.2)` but less stuffy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `${!varprefix@}` or `${!varprefix*}` to expand to all variables with that common prefix (the difference is the same as `$@` and `$*`):

```sh
SERVER_IP48_SUBNET=48sub
SERVER_IP49_SUBNET=49sub
SERVER_IP50_SUBNET=50sub

SERVER_IP=1.2.3.4

# set this as empty since !SERVER_IP@ also matches SERVER_IP
ALLIPS=""
for var in "${!SERVER_IP@}"; do
  ALLIPS=$ALLIPS,${!var}
done
```

This would probably be more practical if you could invert the names like this, since we can only match prefixes:

```sh
SERVER_IP_SUBNET_48=48sub
SERVER_IP_SUBNET_49=49sub
SERVER_IP_SUBNET_50=50sub

SERVER_IP=1.2.3.4

ALLIPS=$SERVER_IP
for var in "${!SERVER_IP_SUBNET_@}"; do
  ALLIPS=$ALLIPS,${!var}
done
```

More info on this feature in [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Answer (score 0):

One idea:

```
SERVER_IP48_SUBNET=48sub
SERVER_IP49_SUBNET=49sub
SERVER_IP50_SUBNET=50sub

SERVER_IP=1.2.3.4

ALLIPs=${SERVER_IP}

for i in {48..50}
do
    tmpvar="SERVER_IP${i}_SUBNET"      # build the variable name
    ALLIPs="${ALLIPs},${!tmpvar}"      # indirect variable reference via tmpvar
done

echo "ALLIPs = $ALLIPs}"
```

This generates:

```
ALLIPs = 1.2.3.4,48sub,49sub,50sub
```