# How to concatenate multiple shell variables into one?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to form a single variable from a for loop.

My script:

```
#! /bin/sh
if [ "$#" -le 1 ]; then
    echo "Illegal number of parameters"
    exit 1
else
    # Form domains variable
    DOMAINS=""
    for i in "${@:2}"; do
        DOMAINS+="$i,"
    done

    echo "${DOMAINS::-1}"
fi
```

When I execute it:

```
    sh script.sh command domain1 domain2
```

I get the following error:

```
    certbot.sh: line 10: DOMAINS+=mmand,: not found
    certbot.sh: line 10: DOMAINS+=domain1.com,: not found
    certbot.sh: line 10: DOMAINS+=domain2.com,: not found
```

It seems as I used bash syntax since the following execution works:

```
    bash script.sh command domain1.com domain2.com
```

I get:

```
domain1.com,domain2.com
```

I need it to work as sh not bash. I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: `"${@:2}"` and `${DOMAINS::-1}"` does not look like `sh` you might need to `shift` , but you can paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation.

Comment: @Sulas : I took the liberty to remove the _bash_ tag, since the question is not related to bash.

Comment: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as
reserved by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then
[wonder why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555060/7552) 
your [script is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just:

```
IFS=,
echo "$*"
```

Or you seem to want from a second argument. Then like:

```
( shift; IFS=,; echo "$*" )
```

Answer (score 1):

`+=` is not valid in a POSIX shell.

Since it is not a valid variable assignment,

```
DOMAINS+="$i,"
```

is interpreted as the name of a command, which is obtained by parameter expansion of `i`. For instance, if `i` equals 1, the line corresponds to

```
DOMAINS+=1,
```

If you had an executable file named `DOMAINS+=1,` in your PATH, this file would be run.

You have to catenatate variables like this:

```
FOO=$FOO$BAR$BAZ
```

You can't avoid repeating the name *FOO*.

An alternative would be to switch to zsh or bash, where your usage of `+=` would indeed have the desired effect.

Comment: I suggest to use `FOO="$FOO$BAR$BAZ"`

Comment: @Bodo: For very old bash version, I believe that quotes were necessary here, if one of the variables contains white space, but at least since bash 4, likely since bash 3 already, they aren't anymore, and I wanted to focus just on the issue of catenation.

Comment: For readability: `foo=${foo}${bar}${baz}` -- quotes not strictly required for variable assignments

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing `DOMAINS+="$i,"` into `DOMAINS="${DOMAINS}${i},"` relying on variable substitution?