# Bash Script Split Hostname Into Var

Tags: bash

I am looking how to bash script a hostname and grab everything in between numbers into a var. For example, let's say the `hostname` is `abcd1efghij12kl`. How do return just `efghij`?

The number of letters before the first number varies and the number of letters after the second number can vary and inbetween.

Also to first number could be 1 or 2 digits and same for the second set of numbers. I am looking to get only the letters in between.  When I try IFS i can't seem to get anywhere.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's 2 ways to do it with bash:

```sh
hostname=abcd1efghij12kl

# using a subshell so the IFS and options don't affect your running shell
(IFS=0123456798; set -f; set -- $hostname; echo "$2")
# => efghij

# using a regular expression and the BASH_REMATCH array
if [[ $hostname =~ [[:digit:]]([^[:digit:]]+)[[:digit:]] ]]; then
  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
# => efghij
```

The key is that IFS is a "set" of characters, not a pattern. If you tried `IFS="[0-9]"`, then bash will try to split using the 5 characters <kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>9</kbd>, <kbd>]</kbd>

Comment: How do i get the hostname as a var without doing it manually.  This works when i set the hostname manually but not when i do something like HOSTNAME='hostname' or HOSTNAME=$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname)

Comment: The [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) syntax is `hostname=$(hostname)`

Comment: Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as
reserved by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then
[wonder why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555060/7552) 
your [script is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).

Comment: when I do it that way i get nothing in return on (IFS=0123456798; set -f; set -- $hostname; echo "$2")  I only get it if hostname= is set manually

Comment: nvm, got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameter expansions in bash (extended globbing needed):

```sh
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s extglob                                   # Turn on extended globbing
for hostname in abcd1efghij12kl abcd12efghij12kl abcd12efghij2kl abcd1efghij1kl ; do
    between_digits=${hostname##+([^0-9])+([0-9])}  # Remove everything up to the first number
    between_digits=${between_digits%%[0-9]*}       # Remove everything starting from the last number
    echo "$between_digits"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
echo "abcd1efghij12kl"| sed -E 's/.*[[:digit:]]([^[:digit:]]+)[[:digit:]].*/\1/g'
```

Output:

```
efghij
```

Comment: You have to remove one `[` in `([^[[:digit:]]+)`, resulting in `([^[:digit:]]+)`. Teststring: `abcd1ef[ghij12kl`.