# use `true` builtin instead of `/bin/true` in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have written some code that uses the `/bin/true` by accident and I want to force the usage of the builtin of `true` and `false`.. any Idea what is the correct way of doing so?

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eEuo pipefail

CONFIRM=false
if [[ $1 == "Y" ]]; then
  CONFIRM=true
fi

"${CONFIRM}" || echo "Deletion will not happen, please run with '${0} Y' to confirm"

if $CONFIRM; then
 echo "I deleted the stuff!"
fi
```

Comment: This should use the built-in if it exists. That said, I don't think it matters. The only difference between the built-in and `/bin/true` would be whether a process is started, not in the exit status either produces.

Comment: you can shorten the code a bit: `[[ $1 == Y ]] && confirm=true || confirm=false`

Comment: Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as
reserved by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then
[wonder why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555060/7552) 
your [script is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).

Comment: and @chepner is right: bash looks for builtins before external commands. At a prompt, enter `type -a true`, and see [3.7.2 Command Search and Execution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Search-and-Execution) in the manual

Comment: @glenn-jackman the shorter code is more voodoo for some. The allcaps have been fixed in the original script

Answer (score 2):

To me, this looks like a job for `if` ... `else`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eEuo pipefail

if [[ $# -eq 1 && $1 == Y ]]; then
  echo "I deleted the stuff!"
else
  echo "Deletion will not happen, please run with '${0} Y' to confirm"
fi
```

---

If you need to save the result:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eEuo pipefail

# with the set-mode above, you can set `conform` like this:
[[ $# -eq 1 && $1 == Y ]] && confirm=$? || confirm=$?
# otherwise, you could just set it after the above test

# truth test
[[ $confirm -eq $() ]] || echo "Deletion will not happen, please run with '${0} Y' to confirm"

# truth test again
if [[ $confirm -eq $() ]]; then
    echo "I deleted the stuff!"
fi
```

Comment: Is `[[ $# -eq 1 && $1 == Y ]]` strictly equivalent to `[[ $1 == Y ]]` ?

Comment: @Philippe No, not if `$1` is not assigned

Comment: If $1 is not assigned, `[[ $# -eq 1 && $1 == Y ]]` and `[[ $1 == Y ]]` give the same result.

Comment: @Philippe Run bash in the same mode (the `set` line) and you should notice the diff if you don't supply any argument.

Comment: You are right, `-u` makes difference.

Comment: The check is required in multiple places (simplified for the post here)

Comment: @goergettica Ok, you could do like I showed in the alternative I added.