# mv command and rename not working on multiple flies

Tags: bash

Below is a bash script to move files around and rename them. The problem is it doesn't work when there is more than one file in the directory. I'm assuming because the last parameter in the mv command is a file. Any suggestions?

```
'#!/bin/bash'
'INPUTDIR="/home/southern-uniontn/S001007420"'
'OUTPUTDIR="/mnt/edi-06/southern-uniontn/flats-in"'
'BACKUPDIR="/backup/southern-uniontn/S001007420"'
YEAR=`date +%Y`
MONTH=`date +%m`
DAY=`date +%d`
HOUR=`date +%H`
MINUTE=`date +%M`

######## Do some error checking #########
# Does backup dir exist?
if [ ! -d $BACKUPDIR/$YEAR ]
  then
        mkdir $BACKUPDIR/$YEAR
fi

if [ ! -d $BACKUPDIR/$YEAR/$MONTH ]
  then
        mkdir $BACKUPDIR/$YEAR/$MONTH
fi

if [ ! -d $BACKUPDIR/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY ]
  then
        mkdir $BACKUPDIR/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY
fi

if [[ $(find $INPUTDIR -type f  | wc -l) -gt 0 ]];
        then
                ###### Rename the file, move it to Backup, then copy to the Output Directory #####
                for f in $INPUTDIR/*
                do
                  echo "`date` - Move recurring txt flat file to BackupDir for Union TN from Southern"
                  mv $INPUTDIR/* $BACKUPDIR/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/UnionTN-S001007420-$YEAR$MONTH$DAY-$HOUR$MINUTE.txt
                sleep 2
                  echo "`date` - Copy backup file to the Union TN Output Directory"
                  cp $BACKUPDIR/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/UnionTN-S001007420-$YEAR$MONTH$DAY-$HOUR$MINUTE.txt $OUTPUTDIR/
                done;
fi
```

Comment: Yes you cannot move multiple files to the same file name. You should probably make the destination a directory of the same or similar name, or rename each file to something unique using the same convention.

Comment: Hi SupremeFFS, what should this script do, precisely?

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: @3Nd_R1m It should meaning I would like it to rename the files in input directory either one or multiple, move them to the backup directory then copy them from the backup directory to the output directory.

Comment: If you run `for f in $INPUTDIR/*`, then inside that loop you probably want to use `"$f"`, not `$INPUTDIR/*`. Also, you're missing a _lot_ of quoting; as suggested before, fix everything http://shellcheck.net/ finds before asking questions here.

Comment: (As another note -- all-caps variable names are in a namespace defined for use by variables that are meaningful to the shell and other POSIX-specified tools; applications should use lowercase names for variables they define themselves -- see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named, preexisting environment variable).

Comment: Also, `mkdir -p` is your friend; less potential for race conditions if you call it unconditionally rather than invoking it only when `test -d` says it's necessary.

Comment: Why do you have quotes around the first 4 lines?

Comment: @Barmar Happened when pasting into stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes:

- Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as reserved
  by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then [wonder
  why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555060/7552) your [script is
  broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).
- `mkdir -p` can create parent directories, and will not error if the dir already exists
- store the filenames in an array. Then the shell does not have to duplicate
  the work, and you don't need to count how many there are: if there are no
  files, the loop has zero iterations
- if you want to keep the same directory hierarchy in the outputdir,
  you need to do that by hand.
- use `read` to get the date parts
- with bash v4.2+, `printf` can be used instead of calling out to `date`

  - use magic value "-1" to mean "now".
  - `printf '%(%Y-%m-%d)T\n' -1` prints "2021-10-25" (as of the day I write this)

This is, I think, what you want:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

inputdir='/home/southern-uniontn/S001007420'
outputdir='/mnt/edi-06/southern-uniontn/flats-in'
backupdir='/backup/southern-uniontn/S001007420'

read year month day hour minute < <(printf '%(%Y %m %d %H %M)T\n' -1)

# create backup dirs if not exists
date_dir="$year/$month/$day"
mkdir -p "$backupdir/$date_dir"
mkdir -p "$outputdir/$date_dir"

mapfile -t files < <(find $inputdir -type f)
for f in "${files[@]}"
do
    ###### Rename the file, move it to Backup, then copy to the Output Directory #####
    backup_file="UnionTN-S001007420-$year$month$day-$hour$minute.txt"

    printf '%(%c)T - Move recurring txt flat file to backupdir for Union TN from Southern\n' -1
    mv "$f" "$backupdir/$date_dir/$backup_file"

    printf '%(%c)T - Copy backup file to the Union TN Output Directory\n' -1
    cp "$backupdir/$date_dir/$backup_file" "$outputdir/$date_dir/$backup_file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a glob with `mv`, the target must be an existing directory, and all matching files will be moved inside that directory.

In your case,

```sh
mv $INPUTDIR/* $BACKUPDIR/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/UnionTN-S001007420-$YEAR$MONTH$DAY-$HOUR$MINUTE.txt
```

tells `mv` to move all file inside the `$INPUTDIR/*` directory to a directory named `$BACKUPDIR/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/UnionTN-S001007420-$YEAR$MONTH$DAY-$HOUR$MINUTE.txt`.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I hope this help.

Some more advice you could use:

- Don't put the shebang (the first line beginning with "#") and the first three variable declarations inside single-quotes.
- Some argue it is more portable and better to write `/usr/bin/env bash` instead of `/bin/bash` in the shebang
- `if [ CONDITION ] /then ACTION /fi` statements can be simplified by writing `[ CONDITION ] && ACTION`
- You reduce your likely hood of encountering unexpected behaviour when double-quoting your strings and variable (i.e. write `"${year}/${month}/"` instead of `$year/$month`.
- No need to call `mkdir a`, followed by `mkidr a/b`, then `mkdir a/b/c` and so on, you can just call `mkdir -p a/b/c`. The `p` flag tells `mkdir` to create parent directories if they don't already exist.
- It is unnecessary to validate the existence of a directory before calling `mkdir` since `mkdir` already validates that for you.
- As pointed out by commenters, all-caps variables are conventions for special POSIX related variables. You should use another type of casing.
- You could use `date` to do the formatting for you: `date +%Y/%m/%d` will print `2021/10/25`
- Strings without interpolation can have single-quotes.
- (Optional, prevent undesired behaviors) Put `set -e` at the beginning of your scripts, after the shebang, to tell bash to halt if an error is encountered
- And finally, use `man <command_name>` for built-in documentation!