# syntax error at line and invalid reference list for the KSH script syntax

Tags: unix, ksh

cd $file_dir

what I am trying to do with this is to do an attachment of a file to from a directory and if the attachment is not found there then look into the other directory and do the attachment

```
if [ -f "${CLAIM_FILE_PREFIX}"*$(date +"%Y%m%d")*.html ] then
  for FILE in ${CLAIM_FILE_PREFIX}*$(date +"%Y%m%d")*.html do
    ATTACHMENT_ARGS="$ATTACHMENT_ARGS $FILE"
    echo "$ATTACHMENT_ARGS"
  done
else
  cd $ARCHIVE_DIR
  for FILE in ${CLAIM_FILE_PREFIX}*.html do
   ATTACHMENT_ARGS="$ATTACHMENT_ARGS $FILE"
    echo "$ATTACHMENT_ARGS"
   done
fi
```

what I am trying to do with this is to do an attachment of a file to from a directory and if the attachment is not found there then look into the other directory and do the attachment

Please if someone could help with this syntax error which I am facing

Comment: copy/paste your code to https://shellcheck.net . Be sure to include `#!/bin/ksh93` as the first line. You'll get several items flagged. Fixed those and if you still have trouble, update your code here and leave a note like "validated with shellcheck". Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

When you cuddle `then` and `do` on the same line as `if` and `for`, you need a semicolon:

```bash
if ... ; then
   for x in y; do
```

---

Also, this is not right (beyond the above):

```bash
if [ -f "${CLAIM_FILE_PREFIX}"*$(date +"%Y%m%d")*.html ] then
```

`-f` is used to test a **single filename**, not a list of them.

Create an array of the files, using the `~(N)` prefix so that the array is empty if the glob pattern matches nothing:

```bash
typeset -a files=( ~(N)"${CLAIM_FILE_PREFIX}"*$(date +"%Y%m%d")*.html )
```

Then, your `if` condition will examine the **number** of files:

```bash
today=$(printf '%(%Y%m%d)T' now)
typeset -a files=( ~(N)"${CLAIM_FILE_PREFIX}"*"${today}"*.html )

if [ "${#files[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then
  for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    ATTACHMENT_ARGS+=" $file"
    echo "$ATTACHMENT_ARGS"
  done
else
  cd "$ARCHIVE_DIR"
  for file in ~(N)"${CLAIM_FILE_PREFIX}"*.html; do
   ATTACHMENT_ARGS+=" $file"
    echo "$ATTACHMENT_ARGS"
   done
fi
```

Notes

- `+=` to *append* to a variable
- ksh has builtin datetime formatting with printf.
- Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as reserved by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then [wonder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555060/7552) [why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552) your script is [broken](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/114596/4667).
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)