# Print lines that have no duplicates in a file and preserve sort order linux

Tags: awk, uniq

I have the following file:

```
2
1
4
3
2
1
```

**I want the output like this (unique lines that don't have any duplicates and preserve order):**

```
4
3
```

I tried `sort file.txt | uniq -u` it works, but output is sorted:

```
3
4
```

I tried `awk '!x[$0]++' file.txt` it keeps order, but it prints all values once:

```
2
1
4
3
```

Comment: The problem is that the uniq command expects that sorting must be done before you pipe to the uniq command, since the lines with same content must be consecutive - next to eachother. 

You can do your removal of lines that have duplicates and keep ordering using Powershell like this:

`Get-Content .\data.txt | Group-Object | Where-Object { $_.Count -le 1 } | Select -ExpandProperty Name`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A couple ideas to choose from:

*a)* read the input file twice:

```
awk '
FNR==NR         { counts[$0]++; next }  # 1st pass: keep count
counts[$0] == 1                         # 2nd pass: print rows with count == 1
' file.txt file.txt
```

*b)* read the input file once:

```
awk '
    { lines[NR] = $0                    # maintain ordering of rows
      counts[$0]++
    }
END { for ( i=1;i<=NR;i++ )             # run thru the indices of the lines[] array and ...
          if ( counts[lines[i]] == 1 )  # if the associated count == 1 then ...
             print lines[i]             # print the array entry to stdout
    }
' file.txt
```

Both of these generate:

```
4
3
```

Comment: ehhhh why not just set the value of the de-duped array index to be a chain of row numbers that match it. then in the `END { }` zone, pre-clear `$0`, set `OFS = "\n"`, ignore all array  entries with more than 1 `NR` in it, set `$NR = dedupe_arr[ x ]`, squeeze spare `OFS` seps, then print it in one shot ?

Comment: You'll probably want to use `$0` instead of `$1` since the OP is asking about "unique **lines**"

Answer (score 11):

> I tried `sort file.txt | uniq -u` it works, but output is sorted

You could take that output, and use it as a list of newline-delimited patterns with `grep -f` on the original file. Use `-Fx` to treat the patterns as whole line fixed strings (not regular expressions).

```bash
sort file.txt | uniq -u | grep -Fxf- file.txt
```

```
4
3
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a Ruby to do that:

```
ruby -lne 'BEGIN{cnt=Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = 0} } 
cnt[$_]+=1
END{puts cnt.select{|k,v| v==1}.keys.join("\n") }
' file
```

Prints:

```
4
3
```

Or, in one read of the file:

```
ruby -e 'puts $<.read.split(/\R+/).
            group_by{|x| x}.select{|k,v| v.length==1}.keys.join("\n")
' file 
# same output
```

Unlike awk, Ruby associative arrays maintain insertion order.

If you want a one pass `awk` you could do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
{ if (seen[$0]++) delete order[$0]; else order[$0]=FNR } 
END { for ( e in order ) print order[e], e } ' file | sort -nk 1,1 | cut -f2-
# same output
```

(Thanks Ed Morton for a better awk!)

Answer (score 3):

Using entirely Bash built-ins, you can do this in just a few lines:

```bash
declare -A SEEN=()
while IFS= read -r LINE; do
    (( ++SEEN[_$LINE] ))
done < file.txt
while IFS= read -r LINE; do
    if [[ ${SEEN[_$LINE]} -eq 1 ]]; then
        printf -- '%s\n' "$LINE"
    fi
done < file.txt
```

*Note: The `_$LINE` as the subscript is to handle empty lines correctly.*

Comment: Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as
reserved by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then
[wonder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555060/7552) 
[why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).
your script is
[broken](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/114596/4667)

Comment: Idiomatically when an array is named `seen[]` it's used for just one very specific purpose and that's testing whether it's index has been seen before, e.g. `if ! (( seen[$line]++ )); then echo "first time for $line"; fi`. You're not using your array like that, you're using it to keep a count of how many times it's index has been seen and then later testing it that was 1 time or many - an array used to keep and test a count should be named `count[]` or similar for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using only `awk`, which reads the input only once, and yet doesn't store the entire file in memory:

- `fo` stores a line's first occurrence into an array. If the line isn't registered yet (`!fo[$0]`), save the current line number (`fo[$0]=NR`).
- `fq` counts the frequency of a line, which is incremented for every line read (`fq[$0]++`).
- Also, the yet unincremented value of `fq[$0]` is used as condition (which is not met on `0`, i.e. the only value that would be incremented to the desired frequency of `1`, and met otherwise due to an exceeding frequency) to abandon the corresponding register of first occurrence (`delete fo[$0]`).
- Eventually, `fo` contains only items of relevance (lines occurring not more than once), with the lines' contents as indices, and the line numbers of their first occurrences as values. So, to finish, only the array's indices need to be printed in ascending order of their numeric values. One way to achieve this would be by using `asorti` (available in GNU Awk 4+) with the proc instruction `@val_num_asc` to numerically sort by values in ascending order.

```bash
awk '
  !fo[$0]  {fo[$0]=NR}
  fq[$0]++ {delete fo[$0]}
  END      {asorti(fo,fo,"@val_num_asc"); for (i in fo) print fo[i]}
'
```

```
4
3
```

Comment: just set `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"` then you completely skip `asorti( )` by printing out `i` instead of `fo[i]` using the same `for( )` loop

Comment: @RARE Thank you for the suggestion. Setting `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"` is a valid alternative, and I had even considered to include it, but in the end it has no compatibility benefits (e.g. regarding other implementations of awk), and is even longer than just `asorti(fo,fo,"@val_num_asc")`.

Comment: While `asorti()` will sort the array `fo[]`, `for (i in fo)` will then visit it's indices in an undefined order and so the output may not be in the order you expect. You need `for (i=1; i in fo; i++)` or to save the return code from `n = asorti(...)` and then use that `for (i=1; i<=n; i++)` to guarantee the order of `i`. I personally haven't used `asort()` or `asorti()` since `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` was introduced as I find the latter far clearer and easier to understand with less potential for mistakes.

Comment: @EdMorton : `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"` or : `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_desc"` etc.. these can directly visit indices in the desired order without having to `asorti()`

Comment: @pmf : well `asorti( )` has even less compatibility with the others that's for sure. One is just an optional setting, while the other is a full fledged built-in function that will result in other `awks` refusing to even run since it doesn't have that function name

Comment: @EdMorton : `for (i=1; i in fo; i++)` is a slightly problematic construct - the `for( )` loop early exits if there are gaps in the numeric indices (e.g. some cells previously deleted). i know it's dang annoying to have to do another `if ( )` statement to check for that condition - cuz i ran into that same problem before